# Handling zip files quickly in Android

Tags: android, zip, osmdroid

OSMdroid is opening zip files on the run very efficiently, do you know, which class in their svn is capable of opening zip file efficiently? Now I am stuck with ZipEntry, which is very slow for my app. Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OSMdroid is opening zip files on the run very efficiently, do you know, which class in their svn is capable of opening zip file efficiently?

They [appear to use `ZipEntry`](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/ZipFileArchive.java).

> Now I am stuck with ZipEntry, which is very slow for my app. Any ideas?

Use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and find out specifically where your problem lies.

Comment: I am partially unzipping - like find folder 34 and display image picture.jpg. Problem is, Zipentry is iterating through all the files in ZIP. Is there any other archive, which can be used for "iterating like a folder"? Or something more quicker than ZIP?

Comment: @Waypoint: This has little to do with Android. Ask a fresh question, tagged `java`, about the most efficient way to retrieve something out of the middle of a ZIP archive. You might consider elaborating a bit on "find folder 34 and display image picture.jpg", so people know what you really mean.

Comment: OK, created fresh question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854775/java-most-efficient-way-to-retrieve-something-out-of-the-middle-of-a-zip